# Can SAS expanders from the same HBA/RAID card be cross-linked?

Tags: storage, sas, expansion

I am building a 24-drive storage server using an existing 8-port SAS RAID controller and a chassis with passive backplanes, which means I need expanders. Currently I am using the HP 36-port expander but there is a compatibility problem, so I have to migrate to another solution.

The alternative is to use two Lenovo 24-port expanders (which I know to have no support issues,) each with a x4 link to the RAID controller and 12 drives hooked to it. I would also reserve one x4 link from each expander for future expansion. This leaves me one x4 link from each expander.

Now can I use a x4 cable to join the two expanders using those two remaining ports?

Comment: Highly doubtful. What exactly would be the point in doing so?

Comment: That depends on the RAID controller, whether it supports multipathed drives. Doesn't really increase redundancy unless you use a second controller.